# How to call an IBAction method with id sender programmatically?

Tags: ios, selector, ibaction

I have the following IBAction method in my code.

```
-(IBAction)handleSingleTap:(id)sender
{
    // need to recognize the called object from here (sender)
}


UIView *viewRow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, y, 270, 60)];
// Add action event to viewRow
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[singleFingerTap release];
//
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,30, 100, 20)];
infoLabel.text = @"AAAANNNNVVVVVVGGGGGG";
//[viewRow addSubview:infoLabel];
viewRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// display the seperator line 
UILabel *seperatorLablel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,45, 270, 20)];
seperatorLablel.text = @" ___________________________";
[viewRow addSubview:seperatorLablel];
[scrollview addSubview:viewRow];
```

How to call the IBAction method while allowing it to receive the caller object of that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature is common to gesture recognizer and UIControls.  Both will work without warning or error.  To determine the sender, first determine the type...

```
- (IBAction)handleSingleTap:(id)sender
{
// need to recognize the called object from here (sender)
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIGestureRecognizer self]]) {
        // it's a gesture recognizer.  we can cast it and use it like this
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
        NSLog(@"the sending view is %@", tapGR.view);
    } else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton self]]) {
        // it's a button
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        button.selected = YES;
    }
    // and so on ...
}
```

To call it, call it directly, let a UIControl it's connected to call it, or let the gesture recognizer call it.  They'll all work.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing tip. I managed to get the tag of the calling view of the method. I have made a mistake in my code that I have assigned the UITapGestureRecognizer to self.view instead of what I wanted it to be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call it, cause you use the methods as as `Selector` to the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, so it will call automatically when there is a tap on the app.
Also, if you can recognize the colon after the name of the methods in the `action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)`, it means that send an object of type `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the method. If you don't want to send any object you just delete the colon and the `(id)sender` from the method.

Comment: I guess he might want to call it from other view.

Answer (score 1):

As you want:

```
[self handleSingleTap:self.view];
```

`sender` can by anything as you like, it's `id` type. You can also send a UIButton instance with a tag.